# C++ pointers, ++ operator behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers

So I've read somewhere that in case we have a pointer p, and some values i and j defined one after another, then those values on stack will be one after another
however that for me at least does not seem to be the case.

```
int i = 10;
int j = 20;
int *p = &i;
p++;
(*p) = 30;
std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << (*p) << "\n" ;
```

Instead it will print these values `10 20 30`
If I commented the `(*p) = 30;` instead inside `*p` will be an empty address.

I thought that the ++ operator in this case will change my reference from `i` to `j` and the `(*p)` will change the value of `j`, but that isn't the case apparently .

So I was wondering what did they mean ?

Comment: With `p++` you make the pointer point somewhere else, and dereferencing the new pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: This [does work](https://godbolt.org/z/yiH2ww) *if* you turn off all optimisations, but don't count on it.

Comment: Re: "those values on stack will be one after another" -- probably, but that is not required. And even if they are one after another, different compilers put things in different orders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays. You can't access an object by increasing a pointer to another object and dereferencing that pointer. In a little more detail, `p++` is defined (an object can be considered as a single element array and you are allowed to set a pointer to one past the end of an array), but the subsequent dereference is undefined.

Comment: It's almost as if the compiler is optimizing under the assumption UB doesn't happen, and so nothing can or does modify `j` between its initialization and it being printed ;)

Comment: Technically, pointer arithmetic is valid for all objects, because they can be treated as a single element array in that regard. But in that sense, `p+1` is past the bounds of the hypothetical array, and therefore indirecting through it is UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'm cleaning up - I think your hypothesis is the most plausible.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that the ++ operator in this case will change my reference from i to j and t....

That is wrong. For this definitions:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 20;
```

There is no rule that would make `j` be stored in a memory location adjacent to `i`.

Moreover, don't confuse pointers (the abstract concept) with what they model (the physical memory address). For most things it is fine to think of pointers as addresses in physical memory, however, strictly speaking they are not.

The C++ standard defines certain rules for pointers and what you can do with them. Incrementing a pointer to an `int` to get the pointer to another `int` defined right after is not one of those rules! Note that even if in your hardwares memory the two integers will be stored in adjacent memory then still incrementing a pointer to `i` and then dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator will point to the next location in the memory not the next variable.

If you would have `int i[2] = {10, 20};` then `p++` will point to the `i[1]` i.e. `20`

Comment: Note that this is defined only for arrays. In case of a code similar to the one in the question, the bahaviour is undefined. It *may* seem to work though.

Comment: @Fureeish yes that true.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have contiguous memory locations, you would need to declare an array. Since your datatype is small, libc allocates the locations. Pointers occupy spaces around declared variables.